# Why is my value incorrect unless I use cout?

Tags: c++

I'm making a C++ assignment for school and I've run into a peculiar problem. It's most likely memory corruption or whatever but as I am really mediocre at C++ I don't know how to solve it.

```
void Inventory::addItem(Item *item, const int stackCount) {
    //find the item
    Item *fi = findItem(item->id);

    if(fi == nullptr)
    {
        Item *newItem = (Item *)malloc(sizeof(Item));
        //std::cout << stackCount << std::endl;
        memcpy(&newItem, &item, sizeof(Item));
        newItem->stack = stackCount;
        current.push_back(newItem);
    }
}
```

I've got this piece of code, where it copies the Item's properties to another item. This works fine, and it carries everything over. Except something weird goes on with the `stackCount` variable.

There's a commented `cout`, and with it commented out the stackCount value is wrong. It will be at around 32k or so.

If it's not commented out, the value will be correct! Which is 1! (I am testing this in another function)

When placed behind the `memcpy` statement, the value is always wrong. Which of course leads me to believe that it's indeed memory corruption.

So I'm really quite confused. What exactly is c++ doing here?

Comment: Short answer: use `new` rather than `malloc`. (`memcpy` may not work - study *trivial copyability*.)

Comment: What is `Item`? Does it need to be constructed? The `malloc` function only allocates memory, but it does not call constructors!

Comment: if `Item` is not POD type, you cannot use `memcpy` with it. And don't use `malloc` in C++ unless absolutely necessary. Use `new` or even better smart pointers.

Comment: Why are you passing the *address* of each pointer to memcpy? Do you not want the pointers themselves?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to use `std::vector<Item>`?

Comment: That `memcpy` call also looks suspect, perhaps you should just use assignment `=` (and possibly overload the copy-assignment operator `operator=`)?

Comment: Your `memcpy` shouldn't be taking the address of those pointers. It should just pass the pointers in themselves. i.e `memcpy(newItem, item, sizeof(Item))`. Though memcpy isn't a very C++ thing to use.

Comment: Probably thrashing memory somewhere as well...

Comment: @mathematician1975 I had it without before but my IDE told me to add that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Nothing actually happens in the constructor, but I'll do that.

Comment: I did what @Bathsheba said, and replaced the malloc with a `new` statement instead. 
@Someprogrammerdude @Yksisarvinen And I don't understand, `memcpy` works fine with it, why can't I use it?

Comment: @stepper no, a very important thing happens in the constructor: the `Item` starts existing. The *implementation* of that can be zero, or thousands, of machine instructions.

Comment: If `Item` is not a standard-layout type, using `memcpy()` to copy one gives undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
memcpy(&newItem, &item, sizeof(Item));
```

What you're saying here is to copy from the address of `item`, aka a pointer to a pointer to an `Item`, to the address of `newItem`, aka another pointer to a pointer to an `Item`.

Since both of these are stack variables, and I'm guessing that `sizeof(Item) != sizeof(Item**)`, you're invoking undefined behaviour here.

The reason the StackSize variable is only working when printing it is pure luck on your part; the compiler is most likeley just moving some variables around on the stack to try to optimize stack/register use, and moving the variable out of the area to be overwritten in the process.

Since you're using C++, you shouldn't be using `memcpy` in the first place. Write a copy constructor and an `operator=` instead to copy `Item` values.

Comment: Is there a reason why I shouldn't be using `memcpy`? Without using malloc, it works as expected. Is it because memcpy is a C feature?

Comment: `memcpy` only copies raw bytes from one place to another and has no knowledge of the underlying type of the data. For one, this means that errors like the one that you're experiencing don't get caught. It also doesn't follow the  c++ rules regarding calling of constructors and destructors. So for example if `Item` had a `unique_ptr` inside it, then the destructor for that area of memory could be deleted twice, which, best case, will make your program crash immediately.

Comment: @stepper For example, if your item has a `std::string` field, there will be a problem: `std::string` manages some memory and will delete that memory eventually. If you `memcpy` a `std::string`, you now have two strings managing _the same_ memory, and one will probably delete it while the other still needs it. What you want is a _copy_, and `std::string` knows how to make a copy of itself. But it involves more work than a single `memcpy`.

Comment: `malloc` should also not be used in C++ code since it isn't type safe and doesn't call any constructors for your types. All it does is give you a pile of uninitialized memory. Any C++ code should use new/delete instead.

Comment: @PaulBelanger Most C++ code shouldn't be calling `new` either.

Comment: True, but it's still infinitely better than using malloc.

Answer (score 0):

Memcpy should get an address of destination and source.
You are passing "address to address".
Change:

`memcpy(&newItem, &item, sizeof(Item));`

to

`memcpy(newItem, item, sizeof(Item));`

Also, as stated by @Bathsheba and @Some-programmer-dude and @yksisarvinen, you shouldn't use malloc. Consider creating a copy constructor and/or assignment operator.